# Attach database using old .MDF file but current .LDF file

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, database-restore

I backed up a database 2 days ago (but I only have the .mdf file and not the .ldf file).

I want to now create a different database on the same server, using that .mdf file (so I can compare data between now and 2 days ago). Is this possible without having the .ldf file from 2 days ago, but having the current .ldf file? If I can use the current .ldf file, should I use a copy of the file as it is referenced by the current database?

Or should I forget about the current .ldf file and try to restore without it, per [Attaching an MDF file without LDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700491/attaching-an-mdf-file-without-ldf-file)?

Answer (score 2):

If you backed up the database your best bet is to restore from the .bak file.  While it is possible to restore an .mdf without the corresponding log it is in no way a sure bet, it really depends on the [state of the database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.logging.aspx).  You can try the options in [Attaching an MDF file without LDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700491/attaching-an-mdf-file-without-ldf-file) and if that doesn't work you may need to use the [EMERGENCY command](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/attaching-sql-server-database-without-log-file) (keep in mind that this is a last resort):

```
USE [master] 
GO 
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET EMERGENCY 
GO 
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET SINGLE_USER 
GO 
DBCC CHECKDB ([MyDatabase], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) 
GO 
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET MULTI_USER 
GO 
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET ONLINE 
GO
```