# MSSQL ReCreate LDF file for database

Tags: sql-server, database

By mistake LDF file of my database is deleted. Now i am not able to access that database.

Is there a way which i can access this database ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attaching an MDF file without LDF file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700491/attaching-an-mdf-file-without-ldf-file)

Comment: Have you tried to `REBUILD` the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Detach corrupted database
2) Attach database using:

```
CREATE DATABASE [MYDATABASE] ON
( FILENAME = N’D:\Microsoft SQL Server\YourDataPath\Data\Database.mdf’ )
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO
```

3) The log file will be created by itself